# How can I map fields from Product to Order Product and Product to Quote Product in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

can anybody please let me know how can I map field from Product to Order Product and Product to Quote Product in CRM 2011.

CRM doesnt allow us to direct map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map these using attribute mappings.

One way around this is to write plugins on the PreCreate so that at least when you save the record it populates the data on save.

For plugin reference, the Quote Product entity is called `quotedetail` and the Order Product entity is called `salesorderdetail`.

Another other way around this, if you only need it firing on the UI, is create some javascript that triggers during onload of the form and populates this data for you.

If you want a no code method you could fire a workflow on create of the Order/Quote product and populate the fields from the product using an update. Only downside to this is the workflow runs asynchronously so you cannot predict when this mapping data will hit the record.

Finally, if you want another no code way to achieve this, and you don't mind investing a little money in a Formula Rules Engine tool I'd recommend looking into Formula Manager by xRM Consultancy and North 52 ([Link to Formula Manager](http://www.xrmconsultancy.com/what-we-do/formula-and-rules-manager-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm/)). This allows you to set up formulas on both the UI and Server Side which would do all of this mapping for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a no code method you could fire a workflow on create of the Order/Quote product and populate the fields from the product using an update. The only downside to this is the workflow runs asynchronously so you cannot predict when this mapping data will hit the record.